# Nuendo 4 plugins

Tags: plug-ins, denoiser, de-esser, bugs

I've recently purchased the nuendo 4 pack after installing I was shocked to see there arent any denoisser or deesser plugins, where can i find them? I tried the steinberg site but I jsut want to knoew if im wasting time looking. Are there any if so where can i download them?  work on the new 15 inch macbook pro.

regards sound samuris :D

Answer (score 1):

Same thing here... I don't usually use the Nuendo Restoration plugins but the other day I was teaching a workshop on Nuendo plugins and to my shock those two plugins weren't popping up.

Are you on a Mac? What system? I'm on Snow Leopard (10.6), and wonder if that could be it. The uni I was teaching at had Leopard (10.5) and they where working...

I think those plugins are VST 2, which might be struggling on the new OS running 64 bit - not sure though. It might also be conflicting plugins. I also checked the content of the Nuendo app's folder and they are definitively there. I even copied them into another place, but they weren't coming up either.

If you can't find an answer here on SSD, it might be worth asking over on the www.steinberg.net forum.

Good luck, and let me know if you come right.

Comment: I'm running off the new 15 inch i7 mac book  pro. Where did you find that apps folder with the plugins in them?

Thanks so much ill let you know if the forum gives me any answers

Comment: @jm-v If it's new then chances are that it is also on Snow Leopard, which probably explains why it's also not working with you. There must be a solution! To see that folder, just go to your Nuendo app icon, then right click and select "show package contents" and you'll find them inside. Please DO let me know if you get it sorted :-) 

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think I've found the correct answer. You need to download the latest version of [Rosetta](http://www.apple.com/rosetta/) and it should work.

Comment: wow cool! ill try it when I get back from work, thanks so much